# Probability of guessing incorrect infinite number of times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose I have an event with probability *p*, what is the probability of this event never occurring infinite number of times. For example; what is the probability of someone rolling a dice and guessing the number wrong infinite number of times.

Comment: Zero, unless you mean something artificial (such as "I always guess $\pi$").

Comment: "dice" is plural. If there's only one, it's a *die*

Comment: @Glen_b Not true in modern usage (as recognized by e.g. the Oxford dictionary). Also not really relevant to this question...

Answer (score 1):

If the events are independent and $0 < p < 1$, then P(the event occurs infinitely often) and P(the event fails to occur infinitely often) are both 1, by [Borel-Cantelli.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)